# Python matplotlib logarithmic colorbar in tricontourf

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently trying to visualize some data.

I have a set of X,Y and coresponding data values.
Due to some singularities, I am hoping to use some logarithmic plotting of my data.

```py
def plot_field(idx, data):
    # make sure there are no 0 values or negative values inside my data

    data = np.clip(data, np.max(data) / 1000000, np.max(data))

    plot = ax[idx].tricontourf(x_coords,y_coords,data, 10, locator=matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(), cmap='plasma')

    ax[idx].set_aspect(1)

    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[idx])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    fig.colorbar(plot,cax=cax)
```

For some reason, this leads to the same color for all values between 1-10, 10-100, 100-1000.
I wish to have more steps.

[image]

Does somebody here know, what a solution could be?

I also tried using the `norm` argument, which does not work either:

```
plot = ax[idx].tricontourf(x_coords,y_coords,data, 10, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), cmap='plasma')
```

## Entire code to reproduce

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import math


x_coords     = np.random.rand((1000))
y_coords     = np.random.rand((1000))
values       = np.random.rand((1000))*1000

aspect_ratio = (max(x_coords) - min(x_coords)) / (max(y_coords) - min(y_coords))

plots_x      = 1 if aspect_ratio > 1.5 else 2
plots_y      = 2 if aspect_ratio > 1.5 else 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(plots_y, plots_x)

def plot_field(idx, data, min=1, max=1, log_norm=False):
    # make sure there are no 0 values or negative values inside my data
    if log_norm:
        data = np.clip(data, np.max(data) / 1000000, np.max(data))

    if not log_norm:
        plot = ax[idx].tricontourf(x_coords,y_coords,data, 10, cmap='plasma')
    else:
        plot = ax[idx].tricontourf(x_coords,y_coords,data, 10, norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm(), cmap='plasma')
    # ax[idx].scatter(x_coords,y_coords, c='red', s=1)
    ax[idx].set_aspect(1)

    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax[idx])
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    fig.colorbar(plot,cax=cax)


plot_field(0,values, log_norm=True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Writing *"does not work either"* tells us very little. Which result did you get and how is it different from the desired or expected one?  Can you provide some test data for standalone example code?

Comment: so both code snippets i pasted result in the same output.

Comment: So the question is, _how do I get a sequential colormap, that's not divided into discrete segments_?

Comment: i am fine with discrete segments but they seem to be stuck to the difference in exponents (0-1000) = 3 segments. I wish to have a fixed amount of segments like 20 or so

Comment: Instead of using a locator and setting levels=10, set the levels to what you want explicitly: e.g. `levels=np.logspace(-4, 4.1, 20)`

Comment: @JodyKlymak this leads to the scale being in log format but the values are also in log format. basically 90% of the colorbar is blue and only the very top seems yellow

Comment: it works if used together with LogNorm:

`levels=np.logspace(-4, log_power, 20), norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm()`